# Is there a function for avoiding user to do any action while a script is running?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been developing a long-time script on Google Sheets, and I would like either :

> - print out a message to the user saying "Hey, it's running, please wait" (with the script really running at the same time)
> - freeze spreadsheet so that the user cannot do anything on it while script is processing
> - any other possibility to avoid user to do anything while it's running (edit : no protection)

At the moment, I'm using a 'browser.msgbox' saying : "please wait till it's written 'script is achieved' in the green panel up there (but in the meantime nothing happen). Then the user has to click on OK, and wait and have a look to this green panel. (It's the French version of google sheet, I'm not sure about the exact content of this panel in English, but I hope you know what I mean).
My client would like something more...free from any mistake performed by an unpatient user, this is why I'm asking for your help.

I've been working a a few years with `Excel/VBA`, it would something similar to `Application.screenUpdating=false`, and `Application.Statusbar="Here is the text"...`

I've been looking for tips on the internet, but I didn't find anything useful for my purpose.

Thank you for your time and your help on this subject !

Comment: I think, you could set Protection on every sheet in your spreadsheet while script is running.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function protectAllSheets() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var shts=ss.getSheets();
  for(var i=0;i<shts.length;i++) {
    var protection=shts[i].protect();
    protection.addEditor(me);
    protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors())
  }
}
```

Run your script here.

```
function unProtectAllSheets() {
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var shts=ss.getSheets();
  for(var i=0;i<shts.length;i++) {
    shts[i].getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)[0].remove();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Cooper, thank you for your answer. Actually I would like to avoid any action using a protection : I found this solution in my researches, but because I'm enabling and disabling some protections in my code (because of restricted access depending on user), I don't want to use this. This solution would work perfectly otherwise, that's true. Do you have any other idea ?